# How decompress and unpack tar.gz archive in download process?

Tags: rust, gzip, tar

I need decompress and unpack big .tar.gz files (e.g. ~5Gb) in download process without save an archive file on disk.
I use reqwest crate for downloading files, flate2 crate for decompressing and tar crate for unpacking. I try to do it with tar.gz format. But there are the zip and tar.bz2 formats available. (Which one is easier to work with?)
It seems that I managed to implement this, but unexpectedly unpacking ended with an error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot unpack archive: Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: TarError { desc: "failed to unpack `/home/ruut/Projects/GreatWar/launcher/gamedata/gamedata-master/.vscode/settings.json`", io: Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: TarError { desc: "failed to unpack `gamedata-master/.vscode/settings.json` into `/home/ruut/Projects/GreatWar/launcher/gamedata/gamedata-master/.vscode/settings.json`", io: Kind(UnexpectedEof) } } } }', /home/ruut/Projects/GreatWar/launcher/src/gitlab.rs:87:38
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

My code:

```
let full_url = format!("{}/{}/{}", HOST, repo_info.url, repo_info.download_url);
let mut response;

match self.client.get(&full_url).send().await {
  Ok(res) => response = res,
  Err(error) => {
    return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, error));
  }
};

if response.status() == reqwest::StatusCode::OK {
  let mut stream = response.bytes_stream();

  while let Some(item) = stream.next().await {
    let chunk = item
      .or(Err(format!("Error while downloading file")))
      .unwrap();

    let b: &[u8] = &chunk.to_vec();
    let gz = GzDecoder::new(b);
    let mut archive = Archive::new(gz);

    archive.unpack("./gamedata").expect("Cannot unpack archive");
  }
}
```

The `archive.unpack` throw error after first getting chunk.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `stream.next()` only returns *part* of the payload but `GzDecoder` and `Archive` would be expecting the full file. You can get the full payload with [`stream.collect()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.collect) into a `Vec<u8>`, but it'd be up to you whether buffering the whole (5Gb) file in memory before unzipping is acceptable. Depending on what you're looking to do, there may be ways to process it in a piecemeal fashion.

Comment: You can start the decoder in a separate thread and feed it data via a channel that bridged by a struct that implements `Read`. [`flume`](https://docs.rs/flume/0.10.9/flume/) channels support receivers and senders of different flavor (sync/async), so you might want to look into those.

Comment: My aim is download a few repositories from gitlab as compressed archive and unpack it. I do't need to save archived files.
Is there some other way to make it easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by kmdreko explains why your code fails - `.next()` returns only the first chunk, and you must feed all chunks to the gzip reader. The other answer shows how to do it using the blocking `reqwest` API.

If you want to keep using the non-blocking API, then you can start the decoder in a separate thread and feed it data via a channel. For exampl, you can use [flume](https://docs.rs/flume/0.10.9/flume/) channels which support both a sync and an async interface. You will also need to convert the channel into something that `Read`, as expected by `GzDecoder`. For example (compiles, but otherwise untested):

```
use std::io::{self, Read};

use flate2::read::GzDecoder;
use futures_lite::StreamExt;
use tar::Archive;

async fn download() -> io::Result<()> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let full_url = "...";
    let response;

    match client.get(full_url).send().await {
        Ok(res) => response = res,
        Err(error) => {
            return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidData, error));
        }
    };

    let (tx, rx) = flume::bounded(0);

    let decoder_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let input = ChannelRead::new(rx);
        let gz = GzDecoder::new(input);
        let mut archive = Archive::new(gz);
        archive.unpack("./gamedata").unwrap();
    });

    if response.status() == reqwest::StatusCode::OK {
        let mut stream = response.bytes_stream();

        while let Some(item) = stream.next().await {
            let chunk = item
                .or(Err(format!("Error while downloading file")))
                .unwrap();
            tx.send_async(chunk.to_vec()).await.unwrap();
        }
        drop(tx); // close the channel to signal EOF
    }

    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| decoder_thread.join())
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap();

    Ok(())
}

// Wrap a channel into something that impls `io::Read`
struct ChannelRead {
    rx: flume::Receiver<Vec<u8>>,
    current: io::Cursor<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl ChannelRead {
    fn new(rx: flume::Receiver<Vec<u8>>) -> ChannelRead {
        ChannelRead {
            rx,
            current: io::Cursor::new(vec![]),
        }
    }
}

impl Read for ChannelRead {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        if self.current.position() == self.current.get_ref().len() as u64 {
            // We've exhausted the previous chunk, get a new one.
            if let Ok(vec) = self.rx.recv() {
                self.current = io::Cursor::new(vec);
            }
            // If recv() "fails", it means the sender closed its part of
            // the channel, which means EOF. Propagate EOF by allowing
            // a read from the exhausted cursor.
        }
        self.current.read(buf)
    }
}
```